# Tensorflow 2.1.0 - Generate TFRecord from CSV

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm trying to generate TFRecords using this code provided here [Here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#converting-from-csv-to-record)

The issue with this is that it's very outdated and a lot of the code was built for Tensorflow 1.x.x

So Is there any way currently to generate TFRecords from CSV in using the latest version of Tensorflow?

I'm really at a lost in terms of finding help :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to access the data inside your CSV file using pandas or another library.

Then:

- Create a writer by using this function.

  ```
  tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tf_record_filename)
  ```
- Depending on your data add the necessary functions to your code. If you are using image data, use the _bytes_feature and make sure to convert your image to bytes by using np.ndarray.tostring()

  ```
  def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
      value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

  def _float_feature(value):
    """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

  def _int64_feature(value):
    """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
  ```
- Iterate through your dataset and create a tf.Example every iteration by feeding it a dictionary containing your data. Here's an example where the arguments of the functions are the data you read from the actual row of your CSV file.

  ```
  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image_data': _bytes_feature(some_bytes_image),
      'float_data': _float_feature(some_float),
      'int64_data': _int_feature(some_integer)
  }))
  ```
- Don't forget to write it in your tfrecord by using this line of code inside your loop.

  ```
  writer.write((example.SerializeToString()))
  ```
- Close the writer when it's over

  ```
  writer.close()
  ```

If you need any other information about it you should consult the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord)